# How do I leave OneNote view from Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, onenote

So in my Teams Lists I have a link to OneNote page, and when clicking it, it renders the OneNote inside the Teams. However, I do not see any way of return back to the previous list view other than going into the list from the main view. Otherwise, is it possible to open OneNote from the Teams list straight within the OneNote desktop app?